# What does + mean for [^SPEAK]+ in RegEx?

Tags: regex

I'm finding that learning RegEx is nearly impossible, since every tool or helper site offers the worst explanations and doesn't cover everything. I'm attempting to work through the puzzles on regexcrossword.com and they don't offer substantial help and/or insight. This is causing confusion.

Here is what I understand:

1. [^SPEAK] = not S, P, E, A, K
2. + = matches one or more of the previous characters
3. Therefore [^SPEAK]+ = nothing

I don't understand how this is supposed to work. What am I missing?

Comment: regex101.com explains the regexp pretty well.

Comment: One or more of a character not S, P, E, A, or K. Ex: FOO would match because it doesn't contain any of those letters. Where are you confused?

Answer (score 0):

`[^SPEAK]` matches any character that isn't one of those 5 letters. `+` means to match the preceding pattern at least 1 time. So `[^SPEAK]+` matches a sequence of characters that isn't in that set.

For example, if the input is `123ABCDEFG`, it will match `123`, `BCD` and `FG`.

Comment: I'm not able to grasp the logic used here. How can one match a preceding pattern, if that pattern isn't allowed?

Comment: `G` matches the pattern `[^SPEAK]`, because it's not one of those characters.

Comment: And `FG` is a sequence of 2 characters in a row that match the pattern, so they're grouped together with `+`.

Comment: Have you tried reading the tutorial at regular-expressions.info

Comment: yes. Their pages are so text heavy that it makes my head spin. Most of the time, I can't find what I'm looking for on that site or others, so i come here to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

[^SPEAK] means apart from S,P,E,A,K take any character and + means one or more time 
So It will accept any character taken one or more time which s not in the list [SPEAK]

> ssssssss is valid string aaaa is valid string SA is invalid string